# STM32F401C - Discovery Board : I2C with DMA

Tags: i2c, dma, stm32f4discovery, cortex-m

How can I use the I2C for read data from the LSM303DLHC(Magnetometer) and store data in memory, in a buffer, via DMA ?

I try to modify the "LSM303DLHC_Read()" function to use it with the DMA but the output on the SerialChart is always 0.

Can you show me an example of I2C with DMA ?

```
   uint16_t LSM303DLHC_DMA_Read(uint8_t DeviceAddr, uint8_t   RegisterAddr, uint16_t NumByteToRead)
{
  __IO uint32_t LSM303DLHC_Timeout = LSM303DLHC_LONG_TIMEOUT;
  __IO uint32_t temp;

  I2C_Initialization();
  DMA_Config();
restart:

  LSM303DLHC_Timeout = LSM303DLHC_LONG_TIMEOUT;
   /* Send START condition */
  I2C_GenerateSTART(LSM303DLHC_I2C, ENABLE);
  /* Test on EV5 and clear it */
  while (!I2C_CheckEvent(LSM303DLHC_I2C, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT))
  {
    if (LSM303DLHC_Timeout-- == 0)
      return ERROR;
  }

   /* Active the needed channel Request */
     I2C_DMACmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

  LSM303DLHC_Timeout = LSM303DLHC_LONG_TIMEOUT;
  /* Send slave address for read */
  I2C_Send7bitAddress(LSM303DLHC_I2C, DeviceAddr, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);

  while (!I2C_CheckEvent(LSM303DLHC_I2C,I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED))
  {
    if (LSM303DLHC_Timeout-- == 0)
    {
      I2C_ClearFlag(LSM303DLHC_I2C,I2C_FLAG_BUSY|I2C_FLAG_AF);
      goto restart;
    }
  }
  /* Clear EV6 by setting again the PE bit */
  I2C_Cmd(LSM303DLHC_I2C, ENABLE);

  I2C_SendData(LSM303DLHC_I2C, RegisterAddr);

  /* Test on EV8 and clear it */
  LSM303DLHC_Timeout = LSM303DLHC_LONG_TIMEOUT;
  while (!I2C_CheckEvent(LSM303DLHC_I2C, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED))
  {
    if (LSM303DLHC_Timeout-- == 0)
     return ERROR;
  }

  if (NumByteToRead == 0x01)
  {
    restart3:
    /* Send START condition */
    I2C_GenerateSTART(LSM303DLHC_I2C, ENABLE);
    while (!I2C_CheckEvent(LSM303DLHC_I2C, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));
    /* Send Slave address for read */
    I2C_Send7bitAddress(LSM303DLHC_I2C, DeviceAddr, I2C_Direction_Receiver);
    /* Wait until ADDR is set */
    LSM303DLHC_Timeout = LSM303DLHC_LONG_TIMEOUT;
    while (!I2C_GetFlagStatus(LSM303DLHC_I2C, I2C_FLAG_ADDR))
    {
      if (LSM303DLHC_Timeout-- == 0)
      {
        I2C_ClearFlag(LSM303DLHC_I2C,I2C_FLAG_BUSY|I2C_FLAG_AF);
        goto restart3;
      }
    }
    /* Clear ACK */
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(LSM303DLHC_I2C, DISABLE);
    I2C_NACKPositionConfig(LSM303DLHC_I2C, I2C_NACKPosition_Current);
    __disable_irq();
    /* Clear ADDR flag */
    temp = LSM303DLHC_I2C->SR2;
    /* Program the STOP */
    I2C_GenerateSTOP(LSM303DLHC_I2C, ENABLE);
    __enable_irq();
    while ((I2C_GetLastEvent(LSM303DLHC_I2C) & 0x0040) != 0x000040); /* Poll on RxNE */
    I2C_DMACmd(I2C1, DISABLE);
    /* Read the data */
    //*pBuffer = I2C_ReceiveData(LSM303DLHC_I2C);
    /* Make sure that the STOP bit is cleared by Hardware before CR1 write access */
    while ((LSM303DLHC_I2C->CR1&0x200) == 0x200);
    /* Enable Acknowledgement to be ready for another reception */
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(LSM303DLHC_I2C, ENABLE);

    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

**This is the DMA configuration :**

```
void DMA_Config(void)
{
  DMA_InitTypeDef  DMA_InitStructure;

  /* Enable DMA clock */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA1, ENABLE);

  /* Reset DMA Stream registers (for debug purpose) */
  DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Stream0);

  /* Check if the DMA Stream is disabled before enabling it.
     Note that this step is useful when the same Stream is used multiple times:
     enabled, then disabled then re-enabled... In this case, the DMA Stream disable
     will be effective only at the end of the ongoing data transfer and it will
     not be possible to re-configure it before making sure that the Enable bit
     has been cleared by hardware. If the Stream is used only once, this step might
     be bypassed. */
  while (DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA1_Stream0) != DISABLE) {}

  /* Configure DMA Stream */
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_1;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C_Register_DR;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)Buffer_X;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 1 ;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_Full;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
  DMA_Init(DMA1_Stream0, &DMA_InitStructure);

  /* Enable DMA Stream Transfer Complete interrupt */
  DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Stream0, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);

  /* DMA Stream enable */
  DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Stream0, ENABLE);

  /* Check if the DMA Stream has been effectively enabled.
     The DMA Stream Enable bit is cleared immediately by hardware if there is an
     error in the configuration parameters and the transfer is no started (ie. when
     wrong FIFO threshold is configured ...) */
//  while ((DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA2_Stream0) != ENABLE))
//  {  }

}
```

**And this is the I2C configuration :**

```
void I2C_Initialization(void)
{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
I2C_InitTypeDef  I2C_InitStructure;

/* Enable the I2C periph */
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);

/* Enable SCK and SDA GPIO clocks */
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB , ENABLE);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_I2C1);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

/* I2C SCK pin configuration */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* I2C SDA pin configuration */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_9;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* I2C configuration -------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x00;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;

/* Apply LSM303DLHC_I2C configuration after enabling it */
I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStructure);

/* Active the needed channel Request */
//I2C_DMACmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

/* LSM303DLHC_I2C Peripheral Enable */
I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my first question is why you have DMA config and I2C initialization functions in read function?

Comment: I have copy this function from the stm32f4 library, in my code I have correct this and move the two configuration function in another part of the code ( main ).

Comment: I don't know if the DMA configuration is right and how modify the "LSM303DLHC_DMA_Read" function for use the DMA with the I2C .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the configuration line for `DMA1_Stream6`. You'll need to alter the DMA_InitStructure and initialize the Tx stream - right now you're only initializing the Rx Stream. Something like the following should work:

```
DMA_InitTypeDef  DMA_InitStructure;

DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Stream0); //reset DMA1 channe1 to default values;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_1;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C1_DR_ADDRESS;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C_RxBuffer;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_MemoryToPeripheral;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 1;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_Full;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
DMA_Init(DMA1_Stream0, &DMA_InitStructure);

DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Stream0, ENABLE);
while (DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA1_Stream6) != ENABLE);

DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_Stream0, DMA_FLAG_TCIF0 | DMA_FLAG_FEIF0 | DMA_FLAG_DMEIF0 | \
        DMA_FLAG_TEIF0 | DMA_FLAG_HTIF0);


DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Stream6);

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C_TxBuffer;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 1;

DMA_Init(DMA1_Stream6, &DMA_InitStructure);

DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Stream6, ENABLE);
while (DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA1_Stream6) != ENABLE);

DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_Stream6, DMA_FLAG_TCIF6 | DMA_FLAG_FEIF6 | DMA_FLAG_DMEIF6 | \
        DMA_FLAG_TEIF6 | DMA_FLAG_HTIF6);
```